# Give every ion-list label-item (filled with ngFor) a specific id

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngfor

I want to generate an `<ion-list>` of `<ion-label>` and `<ion-checkbox>` that has different numbers of label items, so I use * ngFor.
If I click on one of the labels, I should be shown there additional information. That works so far.

My current problem is that depending on which label I click, I have to show different informations. That's why I want to give each label an ID. Unfortunately `<ion-label (click)="emitAdditionalinformations({{list.item.id}})">` does not work and also I do not have any idea how to implement it differently. I hope thats everything you need and anyone has a solution for me. Thanks a lot.

This is my .html file:

```
<div>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let list of list">
            <ion-label (click)="emitAdditionalinformations()"> 
                 {{list.item.free_text}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox *ngIf="list.item.checkbox==true" disabled="false"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

This is my function in the .ts-file:

```
emitAdditionalinformations(id){
    console.log('id');
    this.emitList.emit(this.list);
    console.log('label clicked');
}
```

This is my list:

```
list=[
{item: {id: 1, free_text: "blabla", checkbox: true}},
{item: {id: 2, free_text: "some more blabla", additional_information: "hi this is an additional information"}},
{item: {id: 3, free_text: "lorem ipsum"}},
{item: {id: 4, free_text: "for spartaaaaa", checkbox:true, additional_information: "yay more additional information"}},
{item: {id: 5, free_text: "i dont care, i love it"}}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the item with click.

```
<div>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of list">
            <ion-label (click)="emitAdditionalinformations(item)"> 
                 {{item.free_text}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox *ngIf="item.checkbox==true" disabled="false"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

And in typescript code.

```
emitAdditionalinformations(item){
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you html to that:

```
<div>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let element of list">
                <ion-label (click)="emitAdditionalinformations(element.item.id)"> 
                     {{element.item.free_text}}</ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox *ngIf="element.item.checkbox==true" disabled="false"></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
</div>
```

to test if the id is correct you can try that:

```
emitAdditionalinformations(id){
    console.log('id: ' + id); //add here the actual id to the output 
    this.emitList.emit(this.list);
    console.log('label clicked');
}
```

Hope i can help :)

Comment: Thanks, too. Both answers helped me out!